# iOS Safari play sounds in sequence after one touch

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, safari, playlist

I'm doing some R&D with playing audio on safari for iOS. I know that there are limitations for playing audio programmatically in the sense that it has to be done from a user initiated event. What I am wondering though is if we can initiate a playlist. I want to be able to go through an array and play the sounds one by one after I start with the initial button. My code looks something like this:

```
<button id="play-btn">Play sounds</button><br/>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="text for a sound here" value="hello world"><br/>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="text for a sound here" value="typing a sound"><br/>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="text for a sound here" value="my name is kobby"><br/>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="text for a sound here" value="whatup allisha"><br/>
```

And my js looks like this:

(function(){

```
function createAudioFile(text){
    console.log('audio file create', this);
    var audioSrc = "http://vaas.acapela-group.com/Services/Streamer?req_voice=sharon22k&req_text="
        + text.split(' ').join('+') + "&cl_login=EVAL_VAAS&cl_app=EVAL_7285884&cl_pwd=h1j1endv";

    var audioFile = new Audio();
    audioFile.src = audioSrc;

    if(audioFile.canPlayType('audio/mp3')) console.log('can play mp3');
    if(audioFile.canPlayType('audio/ogg')) console.log('can play ogg');

    console.log(audioFile);

    return audioFile;
}

var btn = document.querySelector('#play-btn');
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.text-input'));

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    //keep this context obj through all new callbacks or function calls
    var ctx = this;
    console.log('initial click', this);

    var values = inputs.map(function(el, i){
        return el.value;
    });

    console.log(values);
    var currentAudioIndex = 0;
    function playAudio(){
        console.log('playing audio', this);
        var audioFile = createAudioFile.call(ctx,values[currentAudioIndex]);

        var events = ['loadstart', 'stalled', 'suspend', 'waiting', 'progress', 'error', 'abort'];
        for( var i = 0, len = events.length; i<len; i++ ){
            audioFile.addEventListener(events[i], function(evt){{
                console.log(events[i] + ' just fired');
            }}.bind(ctx));
        }

        audioFile.addEventListener('ended', function(){
            console.log('audio end',this);
            currentAudioIndex ++;
            audioFile = null;//for ram purposes
            if(currentAudioIndex < values.length) playAudio.call(ctx);

        }.bind(ctx), false);

        audioFile.load();
        audioFile.play();

    }

    playAudio.call(ctx);


}, false);
```

})();

This works in chrome and it plays all 4 sounds from the Vaas account i'm using. However it only plays the first sound on an iPad.

Is there anyway I can do the recursive function and still keep the call stack? I'm passing in the same context as the start but that seems to not be enough? Any help on this would be awesome!

Thanks
Kobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best solution here is to use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API#Playing_our_sound_and_setting_a_pitch) instead of Audio objects. Web Audio API is widely available and even works in iOS 6. This will allow you to have one constant AudioContext that you can layer sounds on, even playing multiple simultaneously if you wish.

One "gotcha" is that iOS Safari implemented the older Web Audio API, so it uses `AudioBufferSource.prototype.noteOn(ms)` and `noteOff(ms)` instead of `start()` and `stop()`; its simple enough to polyfill.

If you want to continue to use your `Audio` method be aware you will have a second of silence in-between. Also, I would recommend reassigning the `src` attribute on the same object instead of creating new ones, to skirt problems like this.

Comment: yea this seems to have done it. had to remember the 'unmuting' process but web audio api FTW here. Thanks!